# What is the 'git' way to check out multiple repositories (in specific versions) in one step?

Tags: git, svn

Consider product  **A**  consists of several small modules. You want to check them out at specific versions in one step.

In svn you can make a branch with the specific versions of the modules and check them out in one step like that.

What is git's way of doing this ? Is there a better way or is it the same?

Comment: git thinks in complete contents of the workspace.  Hence if what you want is located in different commits, it will not work well with git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is git's way of doing this ?

In `git` you can incorporate one repository inside another as a *submodule*. A given repo can have as many submodules as you like. When you commit the main repo, the current commit hash for each submodule is saved as well. You use `git submodule update` to retrieve the versions of each submodule that you had when you committed the main repo.

Like most of `git`, using submodules can be confusing until you get the hang of it. This probably works a little more like the `svn` model than other aspects of `git`, but you should still [read up on submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) before jumping in.